# Using race to prioritize channels, redux-saga

Tags: redux-saga

Lets say that there are two action channels, where the actions of one always must be processed before the other.

Is it safe to assume that

```
const priChannel = yield actionChannel('INTERNAL_PROCESS_COMMAND')
const secChannel = yield actionChannel('PROCESS_COMMAND')

const {pri, sec} = race({pri: take(priChannel), sec: take(secChannel)})
```

...will always pick from priChannel, if it has pending actions - and not, at the same time, pop from secChannel?  Would it be inefficient to cancel one of these takes all the time in the main loop?  Is there a better way, something like a `priChannel.Buffer.isEmpty()`

Comment: I would guess it's safe to assume that for a given race call, it won't take from both channels.  It might depend on exactly how race is implemented, but I would think it's not safe to assume that ties will always be broken in favor of priChannel.  If priChannel has pending actions, but secChannel also does, you might get something from secChannel.

Answer (score 1):

The solution based on the custom (priority) buffer:

```
import { buffers, delay } from 'redux-saga';
import { actionChannel, take, call } from 'redux-saga/effects';

import {
  DECREMENT, decrementActionCreator, INCREMENT, incrementActionCreator, reducer
} from '../reducers/counter';
import { logger } from '../utils';

const name = '13/Channel Custom Buffer';
const log = logger(name);

const delayTime = 10;

const prioBuffer = function(initialSize, highPrioActions, loPrioActions) {
  highPrioActions = Array.isArray(highPrioActions) ? highPrioActions : [highPrioActions];
  loPrioActions = Array.isArray(loPrioActions) ? loPrioActions : [loPrioActions];

  const highPrioBuffer = buffers.expanding(initialSize);
  const loPrioBuffer = buffers.expanding(initialSize);


  const put = (it) => {
    if (highPrioActions.indexOf(it.type) !== -1) {
      highPrioBuffer.put(it);
    }
    if (loPrioActions.indexOf(it.type) !== -1) {
      loPrioBuffer.put(it);
    }
  };
  const take = () => {
    if (!highPrioBuffer.isEmpty()) {
      return highPrioBuffer.take();
    }
    if (!loPrioBuffer.isEmpty()) {
      return loPrioBuffer.take();
    }
  };
  const flush = () => {
    const items = highPrioBuffer.flush();
    items.concat(loPrioBuffer.flush());
    return items;
  };
  const isEmpty = () => {
    return highPrioBuffer.isEmpty() && loPrioBuffer.isEmpty();
  };

  return {
    put, take, flush, isEmpty
  };
};

function* takeChannelSaga() {
  const channel = yield actionChannel([INCREMENT, DECREMENT], prioBuffer(8, INCREMENT, DECREMENT));
  while (true) { // eslint-disable-line no-constant-condition
    const takeAction = yield take(channel);
    log('takeChannelSaga :: takeAction', takeAction);
    yield call(delay, delayTime);
    log(`takeChannelSaga :: delay ${delayTime}`);
  }

}

export default  {
  name,
  saga: takeChannelSaga,
  reducer: reducer,
  useThunk: !true,
  n: 3,
  execute(store) {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
      let i = 0;
      const dispatch = () => {
        if (i++ < this.n) {
          log(`dispatch decrementActionCreator(${i})`);
          store.dispatch(decrementActionCreator(i));
          log(`dispatch incrementActionCreator(${i})`);
          store.dispatch(incrementActionCreator(i));
          return setTimeout(dispatch, delayTime);
        }
        // done
        setTimeout(() => resolve(this), 2 * this.n * delayTime);
      };
      dispatch();
    });
  }
};
```

The corresponding log:

```
  00000005: [Runner] ---------- running example 13/Channel Custom Buffer
  00000006: [Runner] store initial state 0
  00000011: [13/Channel Custom Buffer] dispatch decrementActionCreator(1)
  00000013: [13/Channel Custom Buffer] takeChannelSaga :: takeAction Object {type: "REDUCER/COUNTER/DECREMENT", payload: 1}
  00000014: [13/Channel Custom Buffer] dispatch incrementActionCreator(1)
* 00000048: [13/Channel Custom Buffer] takeChannelSaga :: delay 10
  00000048: [13/Channel Custom Buffer] takeChannelSaga :: takeAction Object {type: "REDUCER/COUNTER/INCREMENT", payload: 1}
  00000051: [13/Channel Custom Buffer] dispatch decrementActionCreator(2)
  00000051: [13/Channel Custom Buffer] dispatch incrementActionCreator(2)
  00000060: [13/Channel Custom Buffer] takeChannelSaga :: delay 10
  00000061: [13/Channel Custom Buffer] takeChannelSaga :: takeAction Object {type: "REDUCER/COUNTER/INCREMENT", payload: 2}
  00000062: [13/Channel Custom Buffer] dispatch decrementActionCreator(3)
  00000063: [13/Channel Custom Buffer] dispatch incrementActionCreator(3)
  00000073: [13/Channel Custom Buffer] takeChannelSaga :: delay 10
  00000074: [13/Channel Custom Buffer] takeChannelSaga :: takeAction Object {type: "REDUCER/COUNTER/INCREMENT", payload: 3}
* 00000086: [13/Channel Custom Buffer] takeChannelSaga :: delay 10
  00000086: [13/Channel Custom Buffer] takeChannelSaga :: takeAction Object {type: "REDUCER/COUNTER/DECREMENT", payload: 2}
* 00000098: [13/Channel Custom Buffer] takeChannelSaga :: delay 10
  00000099: [13/Channel Custom Buffer] takeChannelSaga :: takeAction Object {type: "REDUCER/COUNTER/DECREMENT", payload: 3}
* 00000112: [13/Channel Custom Buffer] takeChannelSaga :: delay 10
* 00000120: [Runner] store final state 0
  00000120: [Runner] ---------- example 13/Channel Custom Buffer is done
```

Hope that this helps you.